# How do you dual-boot xbmc and raspbian with an existing raspbian OS without overwriting the contents of the existing raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian, xbmc, raspberry-pi2

**How do you dual-boot xbmc and raspbian with an existing raspbian OS without overwriting the contents of the existing raspbian OS**

Hi, I am a confused raspberry pi user looking for some help. i have a raspberry pi 2 model b, and I am currently running raspbian "wheezy". I want to also run XBMC/OpenELEC on my raspberry pi, but I want to be able to dual boot raspbian and/or XBMC. Is there any way I can do this without replacing the current files on my raspbian OS?

Comment: I have OpenELEC on a separate SD card - easy!

Comment: @RoyLongbottom Is there a way I could do it with the same sd card? I use a 16Gb Toshiba SD card

Comment: Google for dual boot Raspberry Pi as it seems that other people do it. I would not bother As SD cards are so cheap. However, I might think again for RPi 2 with the micro SD card, if removal is as on one of my tablets, where the card flew out of sight due to a strong spring.